# SplitView’s displayModeButtonItem does not show a title on the iPad (iOS8)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to create a simple split view, Master/Detail, application on iOS8.  The storyboard is something like the following:

```
SVC=SplitViewController
TBVC=TabBarViewController
TVC=TableViewController

SVC---(Master)→ TBVC → TVC -> ASplitViewMaster
  |
  +---(Detail) → ADetailViewRelatedToTheCurrentMasterView
```

Bascially, the user touches the “Items” tab, and a tableviewcontroller will appear that shows the kinds of items (i.e. Customers, Foods,etc.).  The user touches “Customers”, I want to load a master that shows customers and shows the selected customer’s details in the Detail view.  If the user touches a different item (i.e. Foods), then a different MasterView  and its related details is loaded.

The project that I’ve created is about 95% towards a working model.  It works properly on the iPhone.  It works properly on the iPad in landscape mode, but the splitview’s displayModeButtonItem only shows a < without a title on the iPad in Portrait mode.  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, so I hope that you can help me.  I am sure that others may find this view architecture interesting, too, so hopefully this solution will help others in the future.

Here is the sample project on which I have been working…

https://4a1e8691fb88b7b41341-80de7026d6700afa799b216d7fcde2cf.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/MultipleMasterDetailViewsWTab-iOS8.zip

Anyway, I would appreciate your help to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your time and assistance,

Mike

Answer (score -1):

displayModeButtonItem() method handles the left UIBarButtonItem for you.

The UISplitViewController act differently between iPhones and iPad.

In your case -iPad in portrait mode- the master ViewController is presented as a popover, so you shouldn't have a back button nor a title on it, because you are not trying to go back, you are presenting a popover.

Answer (score -1):

Since iOS 8 there is no UIPopover.  The underlying UISplitViewController handles the master (primary) and detail (secondary) UIViewControllers and "vends" the displayModeButtonItem.  Ideally, the title of that button should be the title of the top UIViewController of the primary viewController stack.  It isn't.  I've had some luck, when the master root controller is a UINavigationController, setting its title to match its topLevelController's title, but there are still cases where that technique doesn't seem to work.